# Ping host computer from installed Ubuntu on virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, connection, ping

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on Virtualbox 4.1.8. My own OS is Windows7 x64.
I need having a connection between these operation systems, but there are many choices. NAT, bridge, Host-Only, etc.
I don't know which one is the best one for me. By the way, it seems that there is a problem for Bridge mode.
[image]

Help me please and tell me how can I connect my virtual OS to the real OS and ping each one from another one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two interfaces, one for internet (NAT, dhcp), and another for interconnect between VMs and the host (host-only interface, static address).

good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You have to select in this case name of bridged adapter (I don't know the names, provided by Win7, but in VirtualBox under Linux is that eth0). It is an option, which you have `'Not selected'`.

Answer (score 3):

What type of networking you need is mostly up to your use case.
-host-only:  you probably don't want this.. this will your VM talk ONLY to windows.  No ubuntu updates, package downloads, no contact with the outside world from your VM

-NAT: if want/need your VM to effectively share your windows machine's IP and only receive incoming connections from your windows machine, this is the way to.  The really nice thing about this option is that as you move from place to place (common if it's a laptop) the IP of your VM  will stay constant even as you change networks and ip ranges on your main machine so it'll always to a snap to connect to.  If you need other machines on the network to talk to your VM, though (running a webserver?) this isn't what you want.

-Bridged:  this effectively makes your VM an 'independent' member of your network.  It'll have its own MAC address, its own ip (assigned or it can do DHCP on the network).  Imagine plugging you windows machine and your VM into a network hub and plugging that hub into the wall -- same idea but virtual.  If you're using wifi, you won't need to connect to wifi in your VM, you'll just connect through whatever wireless network windows connects to with the above benefits/detriments.

Ss for the Bridge problem:  Just below "bridged adapter" there is "Name". You need to choose which adapter you're bridging to, so open that dropdown and choose your main adapter.  (if you do an ipconfig /all in a cmd prompt you can find the name of your mail interface by whichever one has your operable IP address